# Using mutable objects as a constant

Tags: java, swing

Adding **final** to a primitive type variable makes it **immutable**.
Adding **final** to an object prevents you from changing its **reference**, but is still **mutable**.

I'm trying to use [ImageIcon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) as a final constant, but at the same time, I don't want the image to be changeable.  Is it okay to just use mutable objects as a constant, or are there any alternatives?

Example Constants:

```
public static final ImageIcon bit0 = new ImageIcon("bit0.png");
public static final ImageIcon bit1 = new ImageIcon("bit1.png");
```

Using the Constants:

```
JButton button = new JButton(ClassName.bit0);
JLabel label = new JLabel(ClassName.bit1);
```

Comment: Instead of making the icon public, make a public method which returns a copy of the icon.  That way the original can't be changed by anyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm trying to use ImageIcon as a final constant, but at the same time, I don't want the image to be changeable. Is it okay to just use mutable objects as a constant, or are there any alternatives?

Whether it's okay is up to you. :-) Exposing a public reference to a mutable object leaves it open to mutation, as you said, so probably not ideal.

In terms of alternatives: Since the `JButton` constructor you're using [accepts `Icon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html#JButton-javax.swing.Icon-), and [`Icon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Icon.html) is quite a simple interface with no mutation methods, you might want to create yourself an `ImmutableIcon` wrapper class and expose that.

E.g.:

```
class ImmutableIcon implements Icon {
    private Icon icon;

    public ImmutableIcon(Icon i) {
        this.icon = i;
    }

    public int getIconHeight() {
        return this.icon.getIconHeight();
    }

    public int getIconWidth() {
        return this.icon.getIconWidth();
    }

    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        this.icon.paintIcon(c, g, x, y);
    }
}
```

then

```
public static final Icon bit0 = new ImmutableIcon(new ImageIcon("bit0.png"));
```

Comment: I haven't done swing in a while, but perhaps `public static final Icon bit0...` would achieve the same thing. `JButton` accepts `Icon` and `Icon`, being a very general interface, doesn't have image setting methods.

(And you can always get back an `Icon` reference from the JButton instance, so the icon isn't really "secure" in any sense.)

Comment: @johncip Icon is an interface, so you can't make an instance of it. If only it is possible though, that'd be such a simple answer. T.J. Crowder's example is what I'm going with. :')

Comment: Sure, but once you've made the instance, you can store it in a variable of type Icon. I've edited my answer to give an example of that.

Comment: @johncip: You're quite right that declaring the public member as `Icon` is the right thing (the answer had a bug which I've now fixed). And at that point, anyone treating it as anything else is into uncharted waters, and so in that sense it should be sufficient. I would probably still do the wrapper, so at least they'd have to play pretty extensive reflection games to bypass it (making the private member accessible, etc.), but you're right that even just `public static final Icon` is already pretty strong. Good point.

Comment: @EdwardYang: See my note above to johncip. He has a good point. I'd still go with the above, but I can totally see his point that even just declaring it `Icon` is, in some sense, sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Because `ImageIcon` is a reference type (instead of primitive), `final` here only means that the reference will always point to the same object. It says nothing about the state of that object.

If you're concerned about someone changing the object's state, you can wrap it in another object whose interface you have control over, or simply upcast to `Icon` if your other uses of the icon allow for that, e.g.

```
public static final Icon bit0 = new ImageIcon("bit0.png");
```

I'd also reconsider whether you need to expose the icon variable as a class constant. If you only ever make one instance of the containing class, then there are no savings from reuse.

As for whether or not mutable class constants are okay in general, I don't think there's any convention discouraging it, it just isn't always that useful. And since they're not garbage collected, you must be careful not to leak memory.